# request oauthlib with smugmug API - get 401

Tags: python, oauth, python-requests

I am using requests and requests-oauthlib to access smugmug REST API but it always results in:

```
{"Code":401,"Message":"oauth_problem=consumer_key_unknown"}
```

I am sure that the consumer/API key is correct. Have I put the consumer key in the correct place (I assume resource_owner_key=consumer key)?

Smugmug provides an access token and token secret when dealing with your own account so I do not have to go through the process of requesting one.

The below code tries 2 different methods - same result. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

url = 'https://api.smugmug.com/api/v2/user/XXXXXX'

client_key = 'Access Token Here'
client_secret = 'Token Secret Here'
resource_owner_key = 'API Key Here'
resource_owner_secret = 'API Secret Here'

oauth = OAuth1Session(client_key,
                          client_secret=client_secret,
                          resource_owner_key=resource_owner_key,
                          resource_owner_secret=resource_owner_secret)
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}

r = oauth.get(url, headers=headers)
print r.content

headeroauth = OAuth1(client_key, client_secret,
                     resource_owner_key, resource_owner_secret,
                     signature_type='auth_header')
r = requests.get(url, auth=headeroauth, headers=headers)
print r.content
```

Comment: There is a (Python / requests)[https://api.smugmug.com/api/v2/doc/tutorial/oauth/web.html] example for OAuth at the [docs](https://api.smugmug.com/api/v2/doc/tutorial/authorization.html).